# MS Access - after Paste confirmation event

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to capture an event AFTER the paste confirmation message has been displayed when a user pastes records directly into a datasheet subreport? I need this to be able to log when new records are created in an audit table.

By capturing the Before/After Update and Insert events, I can easily create a collection of records that have been added, ready to insert details into the audit log, however after all these events have fired the user is then prompted to confirm with a "You are about to paste x record(s)" message.

So the problem is the user may click "No" here, and I can't find any way of capturing this, meaning the insertions could all be captured in the audit log, but as the user cancelled the request the records wouldn't actually exist.

The only way I can think of handling this is to create a temp table to display the existing records, and adding a "Save" button to write the temp table back, but running a comparison beforehand to update the audit log. However, this isn't ideal, especially as there is more than one of these tables.

Comment: you could disable the warning messages that the user receives :D

Comment: Well yes, you're right that would achieve my objective but I was hoping for something a little less brute force!

Comment: You could check for key combination, mouse click, tool bar inputs.  Once you've validated that the inputs are the paste function, set some sort of flag then set the focus to the form.  Once the form has focus, check the flag.  If the flag is set, then do what you need to do.  Then unset the flag.  This isn't so "brute force", but it is time consuming.  [Here's](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp) a link that might be helpful.

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion, hell of a hack though :D It's a shame there isn't a AfterPasteConfirm event the same way there's a AfterDelConfirm. I'm currently working in 2007, but given the choice between turning warnings off, trying to capture paste events manually, or upgrading to 2010 to use "triggers" then I'm going to opt for the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Data Macros you can achieve this. I set up a table, `TestDataTable`, that looks like this which will be audited

[image]

and an audit table like this

[image]

I added 3 data macros to my `TestDataTable`

[image]

The After Insert looks like this

[image]

After Update looks like this

[image]

and After Delete looks like this

[image]

Which generates records which looks like this
[image]

And if you paste data in but click NO on the paste confirmation Access takes care of everything for you. Those records are not added to your main table and no audit records are inserted.

[image]