# Access Trigger - Create table row on update

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

i'm wondering if anyone has a solution for an issue i'm currently having with my Access database.

The database has a number of tables. Once a new record is added, i'd like to create a new entry (copying over the account name and phase automatically if it doesnt exist) into another table - saving others having to manually enter it & minimising the risk of incorrect data input.

I've tried an onChange update function, and while this works, it doesn't check if the entry currently exists in the other table, it just adds it.

Any ideas on implementing this?

Comment: You can use data macros to create a new record in another table. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28079133/726127). The advantage here is that your logic is executed regardless of what form creates the record or even if the record is altered/created from outside Access.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry @Brad I just realised that when a field is changed in the first table, it creates a new line rather that editing the existing line in the 2nd table. Do you know of a way in which the data macro can be written to change the newly created line, rather than add a new one in the other table?

Comment: Use the `LookupRecord` data macro instead of `CreateRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA, this logic should work.

```
IF ISNULL(DLOOKUP("FieldName","TableName","WHERE CONDITION")) = True Then
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "QUeryNameForAppendRecord"
Else:
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryNameForUpdateRecord"
End If
```

The DLookup is checking to see if the record exists, so substitute the field and table names accordingly. Use the Where condition to specify which record you are looking for and you will need to use it to reference your form controls. See link for further help in syntax/referencing.

[DLookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)

Comment: Great! Thanks very much :)